# Amount of warding

Tags: league-of-legends

So I was wondering, after watching some LCS games, I normally place anywhere from 28-36 wards in a 45 minute game when I'm support.  Should that number be higher?  These guys in the pros are placing like 80-90 wards in their games, but since I'm in low ELO (B3), I definitely don't have to place as many as they do.  What would be a good amount of wards in say a 45 minute game?

Comment: As much as you need. Are you safe? you only need to ward if you can't see the enemy and if they were to come to where you were it would be bad. Like if you don't push your lane hard, then you barely need any wards at all (during laning phase),

Comment: Haven't you heard that wards win games?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vision is highly important, no question. But the lower you are, the less important it becomes. From my experience, people in B3 are far too focused on their lanes and do not pay attention to the wards placed around them. I saw a lot of times that the jungler was obviously running past a ward to gank and the laner did not notice it.

Don't make sure that you place ENOUGH wards, placed the correct ones. If you ward all important spots and placed during the game correctly, 28 - 36 wards are completely fine.

Also, you have to remember, LCS is different from SoloQ. On my elo (D2), the players place ~ 50 - 60 wards each game, so well ... kinda embarrassing if you only check the numbers. But the wards are placed at the correct spots and are more than sufficient.

Comment: In other words, put wards in spots that provide optimum sight or a distinct advantage at a given point in time, but dont just place and forget, check it often and watch your minimap for early signs. 
TLDR: Quality, not quantity.

Comment: Something else to consider is that in pro games, wards are being swept very often which increases the need to drop more wards.

Comment: @nukeforum I wouldn't say that. If I compare the "wards destroyed" statistics of my games and the progames, i don't see a huge difference between those. Even though pros tend to use more pinks than people in soloQ, there is no significant difference between the destroyed wards.

Comment: @YUNOWORK I can't check the stats on the pro games right now, so I'll have to take your word for it, but I was more talking about the comparison with TrapHappy's rank.

Answer (score 3):

- Don't compare yourself (especially B3) to LCS players. They are in constant communication and have game plans laid out already. Vision is directly tied to their game plans and such.
- A good support wards keep your ADC safe. You have to ward as much as this is needed. If the enemy support / jungler is spending resources to kill your wards, you have to spend more resources to get more wards. If they are keeping your wards up, you are free to do other things.
- There is no *good number* to go by. It's a stat that is misleading. It's all about keeping vision on the enemy, their objectives, dragon and baron. You need to play each game on a play-by-play basis. If your ADC is getting fed, you may have more resources to ward the enemy jungle. This will inflate how many wards placed for that game.

Comment: Not trying to compare myself to LCS, those guys are at a MUCH better skill level than I am, I'm just trying to get a feel for how often I should place wards.  In the heat of the game I sometimes just simply forget to place wards.  I normally ward dragon, river brush (or tri-brush depending on how much we're pushing), and the brush in bot lane during the laning phase.

Answer (score 1):

Ward is an awesome item and people think the more wards the better. But the thing is that a well-placed ward worth 5 dumb-placed wards. Your wards should be placed where the jungler is most likely to go to your current lane. And, you're just a B3, so you shouldn't stick on placing wards all over the place. LCS is a whole different level, the opponents are unpredictable, that's why they need wards - to control the map. With your current level, you just need 20-40 wards per 45 minutes. Also, your teamates can place wards too, right?

Comment: Yeah but I'm in bronze.  They all think it's the support's job to ward everything lol.  Thanks for the answer

Comment: Well, they're wrong. The job for sp is to help the adc remain his/her farming. If there's no sp, your adc will probably be pushed hard. Also, sp helps not just adc, but the team also. sometimes sp suicide to save the whole team. Sp is a very important role